# Were there any mathematically sound physics theories that turned out to be wrong?

Tags: experimental-physics, history, models, big-list

What are some (if any) mathematically elegant/sound theories of physics that turned out to be wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a good question for the History of Science stackexchange.

Comment: These two "too broad" close votes can we consider as self-critic? :-) @2117 I think your question is far more interesting/useful as broad, but if it would be closed here, I suggest to visit http://hsm.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I've heard that Maxwell equations were developed for the space filled with aether. Then Michelson and Morley proved there is no aether by measuring speed of light in different directions. Maxwell equations are still valid.

Comment: The OP could define what he meant by a mathematically elegant theory. Guided by symmetry principles maybe? That way the question cannot be too broad or primarily opinion based although it still might be off-topic.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by 'wrong': GR is mathematically elegant, but as a classical (non-quantum) theory manifestly wrong.  But you probably don't mean GR.

Comment: @lowtech As far I know, yes he proved, although he tried to prove its opposite. He thought in his entire life that maybe his experimental setup wasn't correct and tried to create more and more sophisticated devices.